# "Management of read and unread" in programmer terminology

Tags: terminology

I'm not sure this is the right place to ask this question, but at least it is about English. I'd ask a question in this forum.

In web service I need to manage read and unread information.
Is there a specified name for this "management"?

I found a expression "Management of read/unread". Is this correct?
I want to know mostly used expression in this matter.

Thanks.

Comment: More context please!  'Management' may refer to packaging of the transmission; or to databasing.  Also read/unread is very vague: are you perhaps referring to 'public and non-public data'?

Comment: For example if you read a email the email is marked as "read" and mostly became gray. I don't know how to explain more precisely...

Comment: I'd just call it read status and "*read status management*"

Comment: @Jim - you should add that as an answer.

Comment: Please tell us some more about what you need to do in the web service. The words "manage" and "management" are very vague and unclear in English, at least without some context.

Comment: @Jim Thanks, so I could use "status"!

Comment: @BenKovitz As I mentioned above read status of Email. Above that there is also management of read status for notification, messages, RSS feed and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are speaking of email, I think it is best to specifically say, as you did in the title of your question:  "read and unread".   I would call them "read and unread messages" (not "information").
I would not use the slashed "read/unread" to refer to messages with these mutually exclusive statuses; it seems to lump them together.

But you could use "read/unread" to refer to the status itself: e.g. "check the message's read/unread flag" or "set the message's read/unread status"